# How to Solve this task ()=4(/4)+√n?

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

I'm new to Divide and Conquer. I would like to know how to find out the running time of this calculation?

What exactly do I have to pay attention to and how do I proceed?

n=1 runningtime = O(1)

Comment: If you click on `master-theorem` tag > Learn more, you get to the Wiki page of Master theorem, which also contains examples for running time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Examples

Answer (score 1):

### so lets see the calculation for this :

**T(n) = 4T(n/4) + n * sqrt(n)**
  expanding for sum k steps it will be like 
  **T(n) = 4^k[T(n/4^k)] + n * sqrt(n) * {sqrt(1/4)+sqrt(1/16)....}**
  here {sqrt(1/4)+sqrt(1/16)....} is Geometric progression
  if we take **k=log4(n)** //here base is 4
  **T(n) = n * [T(1)] + n * sqrt(n)*{1-[2/sqrt(n)]}**
  **T(n) = n * [T(1)] + n * sqrt(n) -2 * n**
  
  you still can use

### Master theorem

**T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n).**

**If f(n) = Θ(n^d), where d ≥ 0, then**

**T(n) = Θ(n^d) if a < bd,**
**T(n) = Θ((n^d)log n) if a = bd,**
**T(n) = Θ(n^(logba)) if a > bd**

yes the ans is O(n^3/2)
{sorry could not comment due to low reputation}

Comment: So the running time is ()=Θ(())=Θ(3/2) ?